# Why does it automatically loop?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about javascript.

At first, the result of the code below is "-1 Hold", but I'm wondering why does the part where I put mark ① automatically loops with the next arguments?

I was expecting that the function processes through of it and put the result with only one argument, then goes to the next arguments. So I expected "1 Bet", "1 Bet", "-1 Hold", "0 Hold", "-1 Hold" would be output as a result.

I couldn't find explanation about this since yesterday to now..  I'd be happy if somebody helps me.

*[This is the URL of the task I'm talking about.](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/counting-cards)

Here is the code.

```
   var count = 0;
    function cc(card) {
   ①  switch (card){
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
          count++;
          break;
        case 10:
        case "J":
        case "Q":
        case "K":
        case "A":
          count--;
          break;
       }   
    ② if (count > 0) {
        return count + " Bet";
      }
      else {
        return count + " Hold";
      }
    }
    
    cc(3); cc(7); cc("Q"); cc(8); cc("A");    //結果： -1 Hold
```

Thank you.

Comment: `count` is 1 for first 2 calls `cc(3), cc(7)`, it decrements in 3rd call `cc("Q")` and then it decrements again in last call `cc("A")`. So the output of your program should be `"1 Bet",
"1 Bet",
"0 Hold",
"0 Hold",
"-1 Hold"` instead of `"1 Bet", "1 Bet", "-1 Hold", "0 Hold", "-1 Hold"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are returning a string, but not doing anything with it. maybe you meant to write it like this:

```
var result = cc(3);
```

also its not good programming to mix strings and numbers like you are doing. when you write a function cc(card), you should decide if card is a string or a number. It will work fine as you have it, but it's not good coding.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your advise!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dev console to test it, it is simple. Only last command return value is shown (Not last line).

You should do something like

```
console.log(cc(3));
console.log(cc(7));
console.log(cc("Q"));
console.log(cc(8));
console.log(cc("A"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!  I used JS Bin (https://jsbin.com/vavebeqequ/edit?html,js,console ) to test it. As I've just started to study javastript a week ago, honestly I'm not sure what is "dev console", but I guess this JS Bin is one of dev console, it that right?

Comment: By dev console I mean tool built into browser (accessible via inspect element). But it seems that js in has the fame behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can see when you are passing `cc("A")` it is decrementing the value.

```js
 var count = 0;  //1->
    function cc(card) {
      switch (card){
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
          count++;
          break;
        case 10:
        case "J":
        case "Q":
        case "K":
        case "A":
          count--;
          break;
       }   
      if (count > 0) {
        return count + " Bet";
      }
      else {
        return count + " Hold";
      }
    }
    
    console.log(cc(3)); 
    console.log(cc(7)); 
    console.log(cc("Q")); 
    console.log(cc(8)); 
    console.log(cc("A"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I understand it :)